# How to restrict users to access my jenkins slaves?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, master-slave

How to restrict users to access my jenkins slaves ? We  have many slaves running, we need  to restrict users to use our  nodes, How shall I control the slaves not to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

When going to http://jenkins/computer/slave/configure it is possible to switch the dropdown "Usage" to "Only build jobs with label restrictions matching this node". So per default only jobs that are assigned to the node are running there. So you can prevent that jobs are running there in case there is no special configuration within the jobs.

But in case a user configures his job that the job should run on node xyz it will run on that node. In case you really want to control it you must forbid the users to configure their jobs, as only this way you can prevent configuring the label a way you don't want to. But I think that's nothing your users would accept. But thats the only thing I know.. hope that helps.